# Cucumber report merging issue

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

Can somebody let me know what does this issue mean in cucumber for merging reports during rerun

issue stated that:-
I am able to rerun my failed scenarios but the report is not coming from two jsons.i have two runner files executed from mvn command but the final report after merge gives me this issue.
could somebody help me in this.

P.S- I am not able to understand the issue in html report with the exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You are not able to use this type of results merge. The start_timestamp field should be part of element c at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument (Preconditions.java:145)

What have I done ?
I am able to execute rerunner and runner through surefire .if there is no rerun the report is displayed fine but on rerun while opening the html I get this exception.

Cucumber dependency-4.2.0
and net.masterthoughy cucumber reporting-5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

It's working now..we need to update the cucumber version I was using 4.2.0 and later upgraded to 5.7.0